# Eclipse - import JAR to the project

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have no experience in Java and I need to build a simple project to send emails via SMTP.

I try to use **JavaMail** https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ for that.

I have imported the JAR file into my project and wrote a couple of simple methods.

The project has no errors but when I run it I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class mail.mail
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address

My project is a simple Java project, its not a Maven project.

**What am I supposed to do to make it work?**

Some screenshots are attached below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by replacing javax.mail with another version.

Comment: Though it works, But Consider using Maven for such projects. Maven is a build tool and it will manage your JAR's in classpath  rather than you explicitly copy/pasting it.